# Generic that extends type that require generic, type inference do not work

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Simplified code example, that should represent my current issue:

```js
type InitParams<Dependencies> = {
    commonFunc: ({ d, name }: { d: Dependencies; name: string }) => void;
    name: string;
};

class BaseClass<Dependencies> {
    commonFunc: ({ d, name }: { d: Dependencies; name: string }) => void;

    constructor(sig: InitParams<Dependencies>) {
        this.commonFunc = sig.commonFunc;
    }

    method() {}
}

class Controller<Dependencies, BetterClass extends BaseClass<Dependencies>> {
    child: BetterClass;
    d: Dependencies
    constructor(r: BetterClass | InitParams<Dependencies>, d: Dependencies) {
        this.d = d
        if (r instanceof BaseClass) {
            this.child = r;
        } else {
            this.child = new BaseClass(r) as BetterClass;
        }
    }
}

new Controller(
    {
        commonFunc: ({ d, name }) => {},
        name: 'name',
    },
    { depends: true }
);
```

[Playground with this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2ABQIYCdUFsDOAeAEQkjgBMI4BjBCHAPigF4oBvAWACgpupKB7LFj5wAYgFcqALigAKFlFIAaKHGzQAvtPmlpREuSo0cAbhVrpOYOgRwA5lHUBKJgwBufBKWOceZrBAsrG1tvDnVQzkoAG1QcHCgAIViIAGEYuMJiCgNqWgZ2Lh5+QWFxKVltZVV-By0FXSyyClyTPwCoS2s7B2dGNw8vTh8i4U6xSmA+dBkcBFtpeCQ0TFxM-WajOmcC319gAAsEHAA6YqFRCUomDrnTgXOyylDfdSHC7n8DvlIZbdewt7RWLxFLCKx8KJRCDoNbZDa0ZQJCDAYDQtLAqAQAAeqLI8SSOFS6Xwejhhjy+WG3EohyiOkSyNR6HRcWePHppKa5JwVN4oys40m03Q0iRKLRxKgAB9YIgUBhsCTGjlNsoOcr4Thtry9ocTqRrqQdTwEAAzWToKA2SyoKgQPjmglE4Ha967XVHU60g3MdBs93qTFRQmsY3ug6emkIOnXOAQADuiWSLJwMnQzliDPFzOJ-t2-xenH+nDjidBcHBkOhMl5O3dfJKF3KcgUVTUPRcrHUijDbWkAHJqhB+z23d3awplThpAKNJxHMYgA)

What i want to achieve:

1. Controller should accepting `r`, which could be a set of params to init a BaseClass, or could be already initialized and more complex instance of the BaseClass
2. Be able to get correct type for `instance.child`, be it typeof BaseClass or more complex instance of the BaseClass.
3. Be able to init `Controller` without defining tons of types for `r` param, so i want to rely on TS type infer.

But, for some reason, `d` and `name` are having `any` type and do not infer types as they should, inside `commonFunc: ({ d, name }) => {}`
Why this is happening, and how this could be fixed, maybe i need to change my approach somehow ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not about generics.
`Dependencies` & `BetterClass` are correctly inferred. You can see it just by hovering call of `new Controller`:

[image]

What's going wrong - is the propagation of infer from `r: BetterClass | InitParams<Dependencies>`.

Seems that problem is about union over the generic type that depends on the generic type. This is crazy, but easy to solve using overloads:

```
constructor(r: BetterClass, d: Dependencies)
constructor(r: InitParams<Dependencies>, d: Dependencies)
constructor(r: BetterClass | InitParams<Dependencies>, d: Dependencies) {
    this.d = d
    if (r instanceof BaseClass) {
        this.child = r;
    } else {
        this.child = new BaseClass(r) as BetterClass;
    }
}
```